What represents an animal 'thriving' in japanese?
I'm trying to explain the living preferences of octopi, where I wish to say "Octopi thrive in warm, tropical temperatures". What would be the closest equivalent to 'thrive'?
The closest phrase I could come up with is 暖かくて熱帯の温度が好みだ, but I'm unsure if that's correct.
Any help is appreciated!

繁栄?  Or just 栄える?

This specific usage of "thrive" is quite English- (or Germanic-)specific. Japanese does not have a word that fully translates it in every situation. You need to choose different perspectives in order to get it through in Japanese.

タコは熱帯の温かい水温を好む（好みます） - if you focus on the nature of octopuses
タコは熱帯の温かい水域に多く生息する（生息します） - if you focus on the overall habitat of octopuses
タコは熱帯の温かい水温でよく育つ（育ちます） - if you focus on octopuses' expected growth (like in breeding instructions)

Beware that you can never swap the word order in the 熱帯の温かい～ part, because technically Japanese does not have an adjective tropical but only noun tropics. So 温かい熱帯 would be a "round circle". Another thing is 温度 sounds awkward in many contexts in Japanese (see: Can I use both 気温 and 温度 when asking for the weather temperature?).

In this context, I feel "好む" would be correct one, like "octopi は environment を 好む". "生息する" may work too.
"繁栄" or "栄える" would fit for historical or regional context like "Trilobite thrived around the world".
BTW, "熱帯" (tropical) tend to mean "暑い" (hot), so paralleling with "暖かい" (warm) feels a bit awkward though...

熱帯の暖かい温度でタコが最適に生きます
This would convey the meaning of the optimal habitat for the octopused to thrive

I don't think Japanese speakers would understand 最適に生きます.

I can believe it may sound odd but I cannot see how a native speaker could not understand at least the general meaning
